# A man with a wife is a husband, a man with a concubine is what?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

As concubines are rare these days (and bastardry ignored), I a wondering if there is symmetry in names of male roles in relationships involving concubines or mistresses as there is with wives, or if it is like the classic Miss/Mrs. vs. Mr.

Comment: A man with a wife is a _husband_, a man with a concubine is a _king_ ;^)

Comment: In the bad old days, a man with a concubine was very often a _husband_, too.

Comment: I think the word is "happy".

Answer (score 13):

***[Master](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/master)***:

> - the man in authority, such as the head of a household, the employer of servants, or the owner of slaves oR animals.

***[Concubine](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concubine)***:

> - a woman who cohabits with a man to whom she is not married, esp. one regarded as socially or sexually subservient; mistress.

From *The Designation of the Individual: Expressive Usage in Biblical Narrative*

> ... her husband is "master" from the viewpoint of status. In this sense, "concubine" contrasts with "woman" in the sense of "wife". ***However, from the point of view of personal relationship, "[master](https://books.google.it/books?id=ucsYoksX3e8C&pg=PA36&dq=%22master%20and%20concubine%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=LhU8VeeZFdjiarz8gIgN&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22master%20and%20concubine%22&f=false)" and "concubine" are "husband" and "wife".***

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=master%20and%20concubine&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmaster%20and%20concubine%3B%2Cc0): *master and concubine*

Answer (score 5):

There are several quotes that describe a man keeping a mistress, as her *protector*.

> Did a mistress wait for her protector to come to her, or did ...

"Unmasking the Duke's Mistress" By Margaret McPhee

> A mistress should never be foolish enough to fall in love with her protector, nor trust him ...

"For Desire Alone" (Mistress Matchmaker #2)
by Jess Michaels (Goodreads Author)

Comment: +1 for finding actual quotes to back up the word choice.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider,

***concubinator***

> *Rare* A man that keeps a concubine.
>
> [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/38425?redirectedFrom=Concubinator#eid)
>
> **concubinate**
>
> *n.* Concubinage
>
> [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Concubinate)
>
> *In some cases, concubinage is monogamous; that is, concubine and concubinator live together in a quasi-marriage* [...]
>
> [The Oxford Encyclopedia of Women](https://books.google.fr/books?id=EFI7tr9XK6EC&pg=PA467&lpg=PA467&dq=concubinator+definition&source=bl&ots=oZgVT-asgK&sig=yIkVNDtEEXSCVYRfZQefblEU61s&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil-aeyl_PLAhUFmBoKHQadCnkQ6AEIIDAC#v=onepage&q=concubinator%20definition&f=false)

[***paramour***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1979%2Ccd_max%3A2001%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22paramour+and+concubine%22&oq=%22paramour+and+concubine%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...23629.36827.0.37572.18.18.0.0.0.0.2169.3561.2-2j1j1j9-1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..13.2.821.8iDsvXx7mBU)

> A person with whom someone is having a romantic or sexual relationship and especially a secret or improper relationship.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paramour)
>
> *It is well settled, by the decisions cited in the prevailing opinion in this case, that a paramour and concubine who succeed in concealing their cohabiting as man and wife are not guilty of living in open concubinage.* [Southern Reporter](https://books.google.fr/books?id=09M7AAAAIAAJ&q=%22paramour+and+concubine%22&dq=%22paramour+and+concubine%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj55s-FlfPLAhXFChoKHULaCA4Q6AEIQDAF)

...and ***dark cull(y)***

> A married man with a secret mistress.
>
> [A Dictionary of Slang and Colloquial English](https://archive.org/stream/dictionaryofslan00farmuoft/dictionaryofslan00farmuoft_djvu.txt)
>
> A married man that keeps a mistress, whom he visits only at night, for fear of discovery.
>
> [Grose 1811 Dictionary](http://www.fromoldbooks.org/Grose-VulgarTongue/d/dark-cully.html)
>
> **Etymology**
>
> cully *n.1* (also cullee, culley) [? as ‘fool’ there may be links to Ital. *coglione*, a dolt, but as ‘man’ it may well come from the Sp. Gypsy *chulai* or Turkish Gypsy *khulai*, both meaning *man*, or poss. fig. use of French *couillon*, testicles]
>
> (Oxford Reference)

Comment: I don't think "paramour" works here. The relationship is neither secret nor improper, and from what I understand, concubines were more "practical" than "romantic".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the sometimes derogatory but modern-day term **sugar daddy**

> **Sugar daddy** is a slang term for a man who offers support (typically financial and material) to a younger companion, e.g. a kept woman
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_daddy)

Answer (score -1):

Such a man could be referred to as a lothario.

Comment: which one? the guy with the mistress, or the concubine? I would assume mistress as the concubine's children can inherit.

Comment: Lothario would be most appropriate to the man with a mistress, although it would not be inappropriate to a man with a concubine (depending on context).

Comment: It should be spelled with a capital L - *Lothario*, since it refers to the character in Nicholas Rowe's play *The Fair Penitent* (1703). But I am not sure I agree that any man who cohabits with a woman who is not his wife might be termed a *Lothario*. It suggests a 'libertine, a deceiver or a rake* (OED) and it seems quite excessive to refer to the many millions of men in western society who currently live with female partners in unmarried, though otherwise monogamous relationships, as *Lotharios*.

Comment: Lothario is not a perfect counterpart to either mistress or concubine.  The former is a name given to a pattern of behavior.  The latter are terms that are given to a role.

Comment: @scottb The OED defines a *concubine* as *a woman who lives with a man without being his wife - a kept mistress*. Your comment seems to suggest they are not synonymous.

Comment: I would also not agree that any woman who cohabits with a man who is not her husband is a mistress.  The word has the sense of "a woman other than his wife with whom a married man has a sexual relationship."

Comment: @WS2, you are very close to my thinking.

Comment: @scottb OED sense 7a defines *mistress* as *A woman other than his wife with whom a man has a long-lasting sexual relationship.*. However it is clear from a 1989 example that *mistress* implies a sexual partner taken by an otherwise married man. The OED takes decades to catch up with social change. But I agree with you that a woman nowadays living in partnership with a single, divorced or widowed man would not normally be termed a *mistress*.The word tends to be reserved for an additional relationship, often entered clandestinely with a married man, or a man with another long-term partner.

Comment: The reason I dislike this answer is that it implies promiscuity which is not always the case.

Comment: @hildred Indeed. According to the OED a *Lothario* is *a libertine, a deceiver or a rake* - not nice words!